# bash script continues to show "does not exist. file "

Tags: csv, unix, ksh, carriage-return

I'm running this bash scripts to read a CSV File which contains almost 10 lines with 05 columns:

```
Variables Global
DATE=$(date) #Set DATE equal to the output of running the shell command date
HOSTNAME=$(hostname) #Set HOSTNAME equal to the output of the hostname command
CSV_FILE='/scrpt/jobs_aix01.csv'
CSV_DELIMITADOR=','

#Variables
contador_sql=0
cadena_sql="error"
## Script

while IFS=\, read col_job_name col_os col_server col_user col_script
do
    #echo "$col_job_name $col_os $col_server $col_user $col_script"

    ls -l $col_script

done < "$CSV_FILE"
```

The script must read the CSV file and run the command ls -l but I get "does not exist. file "

Any ideas?

note: the files exist.

regards

unix jose

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I added the #!/bin/ksh but the same result

Comment: try putting double quotes around ```"$col_script"```
also it appears the ```col_script``` is the last field in your csv file. Is that correct? Do you have anything else past col_script column?

Comment: @choroba: I'm getting errors when in the script when I run  `ls -ltr $col_script` --> the file exists

Comment: @vgersh99: I just did it but the same result.

Comment: Why would you put `#!/bin/ksh`? The question is tagged `bash`, not `ksh`.

Comment: I'll bet anything the CSV file has CRLF line breaks. Use `dos2unix jobs_aix01.csv`

Comment: @vgersh99 this is the CSV content

job_name,os,server,User,script
job01,UNIX,TADDM_SERVER,taddmusr,/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/TADDM.log
job02,UNIX,TADDM_SERVER,taddmusr,/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/console.log
job03,UNIX,TADDM_SERVER,taddmusr,/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/l2.log
job04,UNIX,TADDM_SERVER,taddmusr,/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/control.log
job05,UNIX,TADDM_SERVER,taddmusr,/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/events-core.log

Comment: @Barmar: yes, I ran cat -v and I got ^M at the end

Comment: You wrote the shebang as `/bin/ksh`. That is not bash. This question should not be tagged with bash.